# All Checkboxes are checked when any checkbox is checked in angular?

Tags: angular

I am using checkbox in angular for selecting skillSet. But when any of checkbox is checked then it checked the all checkboxes. How to solve this?

**Here is my skillSet in component.ts :-**

`skillSet: Array<string> = ['JAVA', 'SQL', 'J2EE', 'SPRING'];`

**Here is checkbox field in html :-**

```
<div class="col-md-6">
     <label for="skills">SkillSet</label><br>
     <label class="ml-2 mt-1" *ngFor ="let skill of skillSet">
     <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)] = "employee.skills" name="skills" value="{{skill}}"> 
        {{skill}}
     </label>
</div>
```

**Here is addEmployee.ts :-**

```
export class Employee
{
    employeeId : number;
    firstName : string;
    lastName : string;
    age : number;
    gender : string;
    salary : number;
    department : string;
    state : string;
    city : string;
    address : string;
    email : string;
    skills : Array<{ skillName: string }>;
  }
```

**I want to display skills json like this :-**

```
"skills": [
            {
                "skillName": "JAVA"
            },
            {
                "skillName": "J2EE"
            }

        ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `label for` and `input name` are the same for every input.
You need to specify them.
Something like `name="skills-{{skill}}"`

EDIT: please try this:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
     <label for=""skills-{{skill}}" class="ml-2 mt-1" *ngFor ="let skill of skillSet">
     <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)] = "employee.skills" name="skills-{{skill}}" value="{{skill}}"> 
        {{skill}}
     </label>
</div>
```

### ----------------------

EDIT Nr. 2:

```
<div *ngFor="let skill of skills">
  <label for="{{skill.skillName}}" class="ml-2 mt-1" > {{skill.skillName}} </label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="{{skill.skillName}}" value="{{skill.skillName}}">
</div>
```

and:

```
skills = [
  {
    skillName: "JAVA"
  },
  {
    skillName: "J2EE"
  }

  ];
```

Comment: Is it same problem?

Comment: Please try my "EDIT" version.
Is the error happen again?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to do:

```
 [name]="skill"
```

Comment: Thanks @pixelbits. But one issue is there , it is not showing all checkbox label at once. It is coming one by one when it is checked.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
<!-- inside an *ngFor -->
     <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)] = "employee.skills" name="skills" value="{{skill}}">
```

every input has the same `ngModel`. By checking/unchecking one, you're updating the value of the one common `employee.skills`.

You can declare - idk, a map, an array, a plain object? - of checked skills, and bind every input to its own variable:

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)] = "employee.skillsDictionary[skill]"
```

Comment: For this i have to create one skillsDictionary dictionary object inside component.ts?  I am not getting it. How to do it? Please elaborate man.

Comment: `skillsDictionary` would be a property of `employee`. If you aren't displaying more than one employee in the component, you can make `skillsDictionary` global.